# How to select the default cluster in a Cox model in R?

Tags: r, cox-regression

I'm working on a Cox model and I have a variable which is cut in clusters.

Here is some working example :

```
lung2=lung
lung2$age.cl = cut(lung2$age, c(40,50,60,70,80,90))
cox = coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age.cl, data =  lung2)
```

It returns this table :

```
                coef exp(coef) se(coef)    z     p
age.cl(50,60]  0.184     1.202    0.297 0.62 0.536
age.cl(60,70]  0.237     1.267    0.288 0.82 0.411
age.cl(70,80]  0.532     1.703    0.309 1.73 0.085
age.cl(80,90]  3.926    50.707    0.825 4.76 2e-06
```

By default, `coxph` calculate everything with the first cluster as default. But what if the clinical default were 70-80yo and not 40-50yo ?

**How can I tell coxph to take the n'th cluster as default ?**

Comment: you can [relevel](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/relevel.html) `age.cl` and make whichever level you'd like as the reference group

Answer (score 1):

```
lung2=lung
lung2$age.cl = cut(lung2$age, c(40,50,60,70,80,90))
lung2$age.cl_relevel <- relevel(lung2$age.cl, '(70,80]')
cox = coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age.cl_relevel, data =  lung2)
```